Conditional Data Extraction from Nested JSON Using Recursive Search Fails to Return Non-Empty Specific Values
I'm working on a Python script to extract specific values from (several 100,000) deeply nested JSON files. While my script correctly extracts most of the desired fields using recursive searching, it fails to properly handle conditional extractions specified in a CONDITIONAL_EXTRACTIONS dictionary. Specifically, I'm trying to:
Extract cna.descriptions.value only if the corresponding cna.descriptions.lang is in ['en', 'eng', 'english'].
Extract cna.problemTypes.descriptions.description only if the corresponding cna.problemTypes.descriptions.lang is in ['en', 'eng', 'english'].
Return True for the is_kev key only if metrics.other.type equals 'kev'.
Example JSON Structure:
{
    "containers": {
        "cna": {
            "descriptions": [
                {"lang": "en", "value": "English description"},
                {"lang": "fr", "value": "Description en français"}
            ],
            "problemTypes": [
                {
                    "descriptions": [
                        {"lang": "en", "description": "Cross-site Scripting (XSS)"},
                        {"lang": "de", "description": "Deutscher Text"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "metrics": {
        "other": {"type": "kev"}
    }
}

Code Context:
I'm using the following structure to define what to extract:
EXTRACTIONS = {
    'cve_id': ['cveMetadata.cveId'],
    ... # There's a bunch more keys I'm trying to extract
    'cve_desc': ['cna.descriptions'],
    'cwe_desc': ['cna.problemTypes.descriptions'],
    'is_kev': ['metrics.other.type']
}

CONDITIONAL_EXTRACTIONS = {
    'cve_desc': {
        'paths': ['cna.descriptions'],
        'condition': lambda _, full_data: [
            desc.get('value').strip() for desc in full_data
            .get('cna', {}).get('descriptions', [])
            if desc.get('lang').strip().lower() in ['en', 'eng', 'english']
        ]
    },
    'cwe_desc': {
        'paths': ['cna.problemTypes.descriptions'],
        'condition': lambda _, full_data: [
            desc.get('description').strip() for cwe in full_data
            .get('cna', {}).get('problemTypes', [])
            for desc in cwe.get('descriptions', [])
            if desc.get('lang').strip().lower() in ['en', 'eng', 'english']
        ]
    },
    'is_kev': {
        'paths': ['metrics.other.type'],
        'condition': lambda value, _: value == 'kev'
    }
}

The extraction function is designed to apply the specified conditions where necessary and is called within a process_files method of my JSONParser class:
def deep_search(data, target_keys, condition=None):
    results = []

    def recursive_search(current_data, keys, full_data):
        if not keys or not isinstance(current_data, (dict, list)):
            return None
        current_key = keys[0]

        if isinstance(current_data, dict):
            if current_key in current_data:
                value = current_data[current_key]
                if len(keys) == 1:
                    if isinstance(value, list) and condition:
                        results.extend(condition(None, full_data))
                    elif condition is None or condition(value, full_data):
                        results.append(value)
                else:
                    recursive_search(current_data[current_key], keys[1:], full_data)
            for value in current_data.values():
                recursive_search(value, keys, full_data)
        elif isinstance(current_data, list):
            for item in current_data:
                recursive_search(item, keys, full_data)

    for key_path in target_keys:
        keys = key_path.split('.')
        recursive_search(data, keys, data)

    return results[0] if len(results) == 1 else results or pd.NA

def extract_file_data(
        file_path: str,
        extraction_mapping: Dict[str, List[str]]
    ) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    """ Extract relevant data from a single JSON file. """
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
        # Extract data using deep search
        extracted_data = {}
        for key, paths in extraction_mapping.items():
            # Handle conditional extractions
            if key in CONDITIONAL_EXTRACTIONS:
                condition_info = CONDITIONAL_EXTRACTIONS[key]
                condition = condition_info.get('condition')
                result = deep_search(data, condition_info['paths'], condition)
            else:
                # Perform unconditional search for each key
                result = deep_search(data, paths)
            extracted_data[key] = result
            print(f"Key: {key}, Paths: {paths}, Result: {result}")
        # Return the extracted data
        return extracted_data
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error processing {file_path}: {e}')
        return {}


The deep_search function works correctly for unconditional extractions but fails to apply the conditions properly or return the correct results for CONDITIONAL_EXTRACTIONS. For example:
For cve_desc and cwe_desc, the function returns nothing and it makes no sense to me.
For is_kev, the condition returns the actual value 'kev' and None instead of True or False.
The print statements in deep_search show "Value"s for these conditional keys that are one level above the value I'm looking for, which is in line with what I expect, since the lambda function is using get methods from this level to find the desired keys, yet the extract_file_data print statements confirm that results are None.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
